# How can I match XNA with Windows Form in VS 2019?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, xna-4.0

I'm trying to create a music player with an audio visualizer starting from a windows game project on VS 2019. To do so I created a custom display, draggable from the toolbox, in order to put it inside a form.

From tutorials I've seen it is necessary to include three classes from `GraphicsDevice` and I've done it, but when I put them inside the code, the `Display` class does not inherit and VS does not recognize the keywords.

To be precise `WinFormsGraphicsDevice` is marked as an error, and its methods as well.

Does anybody have any hints about this?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsGame2.CustomControls
{
    public class Display : WinFormsGraphicsDevice.GraphicsDeviceControl
    {
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            
        }

        protected override void Draw()
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing using `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework; Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;`. -- That also looks like the base example Control you find in the XNA docs. Not sure whether it initializes its own `GraphicsDeviceService`, or you need to override or initialize it yourself (IIRC in OnCreateControl or OnHandleCreated -- IIRC2, it doesn't work very well in design mode, so checking `DesignMode` can be important, if the base Controls doesn't do it itself).

Comment: If the `WinFormsGraphicsDevice.GraphicsDeviceControl` is part of a different namespace or an Assembly, you need to add a reference to those, too.

Comment: Yes, I add a WinFormsGraphicsDevice folder to the assembly, it contains those three classes from GraphicsDevice, but I don't know how to make reference to it in the script.

Comment: If you added files to a Folder in a Project, verify what is the current namespace. assigned to those classes. It may have changed, if you used Visual Studio to both add a Folder and move the files.

Comment: How can I verify/visualize that namespace from VS?

Comment: Thanks you a lot, finally I found the right namespace and it builds properly.